# Websphere - Rest service - Certificate chaining error

Tags: spring, rest, certificate, resttemplate

I am trying to connect Rest service from my application. And my application is deployed to WAS server.

I am using Spring RestTemplate to consumer the rest service and everything working fine in my local WAS setup.

But when i deploy my code to QA environment (lower environment region), i am getting below error in my log file.

```
    [4/30/18 17:18:22:355 EDT] 00000207 SystemErr     R org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://host:port/resourcename": com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=XXX Root CA, O="The XXX Services Group, Inc." is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=XXX Root CA, O="The XXX Services Group, Inc." is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[4/30/18 17:18:22:355 EDT] 00000207 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607)
[4/30/18 17:18:22:356 EDT] 00000207 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
[4/30/18 17:18:22:357 EDT] 00000207 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:357)
```

I have imported the certs for the port and host using signer certificate option, but still the issue not resolved (Also tried importing root certs). Can any one let me know what could be the issue?

Comment: This looks like the JVM you are using does not trust one of the intermediate certificates, as the error suggests.

The question I have is, are the client (your code) and server (Rest service provider) on the same WAS ? If not and you used the "Retrieve from port" option, that does not always retrieve the whole certificate chain ... here, you seem to be missing an intermediate certificate. If you used the "Add a local certificate", did you have all intermediate certificates ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/install/t_exchange_keys_network.html

Comment: @thecarpy - Both client & server are on different server. I have downloaded the Root certificate using browser and installed that using Add button under signer certificate option.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the JVM you are using does not trust one of the intermediate certificates, as the error suggests.

You need to retrieve the whole certificate chain, not just the root CA certificate and the certificate of the server. You can use your browser or `openssl` to retrieve the certificate chain. Your client JVM MUST trust each and every certificate in the certificate chain.

See the following:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux